# Connect dot net core application to vitess data base

Tags: vitess, kubernetes-vitess

We deployed dot net core application in kubernetes and we started to use vitess database to scale mysql. How can we connect dot net core application with vitess?

Comment: How did you bring up vitess? Did you helm charts or the planetscale operator? The recommended way is to make sure that you start vtgate with mysql protocol enabled and use dot net's mysql driver. You're probably the first one doing. So, you should report issues if you run into problems.

Comment: @SuguSougoumarane We have deployed Vitess in Kubernetes using Helm Charts and exposed VTGate through node Port as it was was mentioned in the Vitess documentation, we are able to connect VTGate from dot net core using my Sql Driver but i am not sure on how to expose VTGate in Production and connect

Comment: Exposing VTGate in production has many options. You could expose it as a k8s service, or use an Elastic Load Balancer, etc. Essentially, use the same techniques others use to expose a stateless workload.